# Difference between NER, NERC and NEL

Tags: nlp, named-entity-recognition, information-extraction

What is the difference between named entity recognition,  named entity recognition and classification, named entity linking? Would appreciate a practical example.

Answer (score 3):

`Former president Clinton visits the White House.`

- NER: Clinton, White House (defined by start and end positions)
- NERC: NER + Clinton is a person, the White House is an organization
- NEL: NERC + Clinton: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bill_Clinton , the White House: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/White_House

Usually when people say NER now, they mean NERC. Also it is really task-specific, the White House may be a location, links can come from a semantic knowledge base, etc.

Comment: Thanks for reply and sorry for generic question

Comment: I thought that NERC classify an entire document and not a single concept.
For example, referring to the previous text: NERC: Politics

Answer (score 0):

Named entity recognition is a sub-field in information extraction and refers to finding some predefined entity in text, like Person, Organization, Gene, etc... It came out of MUC-6, the Sixth Message Understanding Conference and has been around for decades.

Take the sentence "Google reported 17 billion dollars in profit in 2014, and its revenue continues to grow."  An example of output using a NER tool to find Organizations would be the character offsets 0 and 6 - indicating that an Organization has been identified in that location in text. Named entity linking would establish a link between the text "Google" and a link to the Google (the company) webpage on wikipedia which is traditionally used for linking.

Classification in the NLP context usually refers to document classification and has nothing to do with Information Extraction like your other cases. One area would be sentiment analysis, which declares documents as positive, negative or neutral. My example sentence with Google might be declared neutral in this context.